# How to Subnet 172.168.0.0 to find required number of subnet

Tags: subnet

Can anyone help me here?

172.168.0.0

255.255.0.0

Required number of subnet = 500 (not host/subnet)

my solution:

2^9 = 512 (closest number to 500)

So, 
9 ones from the 3rd octet which goes till the last octet

11111111.11111111.11111111.10000000

255.255.255.128

I know there is mistake somewhere in my process as 255.255.255.128 is a class C subnet. But I cannot figure out what mistake I did here. Please also mention the host/subnet range.
Thank you

Comment: what are you trying to do? are you trying to create a supernet? Why do you need 500 subnets for?

Comment: And why, exactly,  do you believe that your answer is wrong?

Comment: Network classes are dead, killed in 1993 by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). Modern networking doesn't use classes, Please let them rest in peace. Besides, network classes were never defined by the mask, but by the first bits of the address.

Answer (score 2):

That is right. However, maybe it needs some explaining and you have the 172.168.0.0 subnet wrong I think. There is no 172.168.0.0 private non-routable network. These are the 3 non-routable networks reserved by IANA:

- **10.0.0.0/8** Range: 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255
- **172.16.0.0/12** Range: 172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255
- **192.168.0.0/16** Range: 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255

https://www.arin.net/knowledge/address_filters.html

So, I think you either mean to use 172.16.0.0 or you mean to use 192.168.0.0 but 172.168.0.0 is NOT a private network range that should be used on a network.

I'm going to explain based on using 172.16.0.0.

**172.16.0.0/25** (Subnet 255.255.255.128) is correct. This will subnet the larger **172.16.0.0/16** subnet into **512** additional subnets each with **128** hosts.

Your 512 subnet range will be **172.16.0.0** through **172.16.255.128**.
You're making things difficult with this odd request, but if this is what you want to do then the first 5 networks would be:

- **172.16.0.0/25**   Range: 172.16.0.0 - 172.16.0.127
- **172.16.0.128/25**    Range: 172.16.0.128 - 172.16.0.255
- **172.16.1.0/25**    Range: 172.16.1.0 - 172.16.1.127
- **172.16.1.128/25**    Range: 172.16.1.128 - 172.16.1.255
- **172.16.2.0/25**    Range: 172.16.2.0 - 172.16.2.127

Hope you pass your subnetting exam, because that is the only scenario that this would ever come up. :)